# Error: No matching distribution found for webdriver

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

i have on the latest version of pip and also installed selenium but webdriver given an error.
[image]

Comment: Need more details about your configuration first read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask]. It will help you craft solid questions that will hopefully get useful answers.  What are you trying to accomplish if you installed selenium already?  Should this work?

Comment: no this not work,

Comment: C:\Users\Dextor>pip install webdriver
Collecting webdriver
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement webdriver (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for webdriver

Answer (score 3):

I believe the correct package name is [`selenium`](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/) so you need to amend your command to look like:

```
pip install -U selenium
```

References just in case:

- [Downloading Python bindings for Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html#downloading-python-bindings-for-selenium)
- [Selenium With Python](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Selenium+With+Python)
- [Getting Started with Selenium and Python](https://stackabuse.com/getting-started-with-selenium-and-python/)